# Can I create a connected web part using Silverlight in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: 2007, web-part, silverlight

Currently, I have a connected web part that consumes a SharePoint list and uses the data to add locations to a Google Map control.

What I'd like to do is use the Bing Maps Silverlight control and use the same data to render pushpins on the map. I can create an unconnected web part and use the SharePoint web services to access the list data, loop through the rows and add the pins to the map. In terms of configuration this will mean the user will need to enter the list name (or Guid) in the properties of the web part, whereas before they could select from the available lists on the site, this seems like a step in the wrong direction.

So, is there a way to use the data that is provided by the connected web part and make it available to the Silverlight control?

Cheers,
Stuart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you modify your existing Google web part to produce the appropriate javascript code for your Silverlight web part? You can see an example of the Bing javascript produced through a data view web part in [my maps series](http://blogs.microlinkllc.com/tresing/archive/2009/06/10/google-maps-and-virtual-earth-now-bing-maps-series-summary.aspx).

Comment: I didn't modify my existing web part but I've managed to use JavaScript and the HTML Bridge in Silverlight to add pushpins to the map.

Comment: Glad that you found the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The list view web part is just a connection consumer and not a provider. You could sub-class the ListViewWebPart and add a custom connection provider to it with the current list id.

Comment: OK, sounds like a good starting point, but how would I get the list data from the web part into the Silverlight control?